# Mod Rewrite enabled and AllowOverride set to All, but .htaccess still not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos7, httpd.conf

I'm running Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7. As the title says, I've verified that mod rewrite is enabled, and this is what my httpd.conf looks like

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But for some reason, my .htaccess still isn't working. Right now I'm just putting all my instructions in the same Directory element (I didn't copy that part, and I know it's not the issue because I only did it as a last resort after not being able to get the .htaccess to work). If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "not working" is a bit vague. What happens exactly? Is your `.htaccess` file located at `/var/www/html/.htaccess`? Is it being processed at all (how do you know)?

Comment: @MrWhite sorry, should've been more clear. Yes it's located there, and it's not being processed at all. The code I have in it works correctly when placed in the directory element in my httpd.conf. Not only this, but I read on another thread that you can check if it's being processed by putting random gibberish in it and seeing if you get an error 500, which I tried and got no error.

Comment: It's possible that something else in your config is overriding this. Is your `<Directory>` container in the main server config (a _server_ context)? Or in a virtual host (a _virtualhost_ context)? Do you have any vHosts defined? Do you have any other `<Directory>` containers? Can you find `AllowOverride` anywhere else in your config? (There should be a `<Directory /> AllowOverride None </Directory>` - but don't change that.)